# Android eclipse, changing min SDK version doesn't trigger Lint errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to see what all I would have to change in my code to support older versions of the API (before 14).  I thought Lint would throw errors anywhere in the code I was calling a later API unchecked but I can't get this to happen even after clearing Lint markers and cleaning and refreshing the project many times.

Any ideas?

edit: I've discovered if I go to each file individually and make changes to it, and then save it, then Lint is checking for errors.  This would be very tedious to do for each file however.

Comment: Is there a specific line of code that you believe should throw a lint warning? Not all applications call newer API methods, so may just have coincidentally avoided newer API calls.

Comment: Well I know there are certain things I've used throughout the code, like `View.callOnClick()` which requires API 15 instead of `performClick`.  But even those won't throw errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click on your project and under `Android Tools` You will find `Run Lint: Check for Common Errors`. That should do it